# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a6c50)

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm quite new at Android developpement, and I've been trying to fix this for the last day but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Context mContext = this; is done in the onCreate of the Activity.

I have no other informations in the LogCat than : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418a6c50)

This method is called from the postExecute of an asyncTask.
The code inside the run() is called and crashes in between the log"run launched" and the log"texts set"...

```
public void updateUiMethod(final Boolean updateTxt) {

    ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // update your UI here and be sure to give the activity context, not getApplicationContext();
            if(updateTxt) {
                Log.e("mytag","run launched");

                credit.setText(creditsValue);
                expiration.setText(fidelityValue);
                Log.e("mytag","texts set");
                if(userStatusText.equals(STATUS_SUBSCRIPTION)) {
                    // AFFICHER LE INFINITY
                    Log.e("mytag","first");
                    statut.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.credits_userstatus_subscriber));
                    credit.setText("∞");
                } else if (userStatusText.equals(STATUS_DISCOVER)) {
                    statut.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.credits_userstatus_discovery));
                } else if (userStatusText.equals(STATUS_ONESHOT)) {
                    statut.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.credits_userstatus_units));
                } else {
                    statut.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.credits_userstatus_premium));
                }
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
            builder.setMessage(alertMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            Log.e("mytag", "alert créée");
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the postExecute :

```
          @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
            // do something     
            Log.e("tag",jsonForPostExecute.toString());
            try {
                if (jsonForPostExecute.getString("error") != null) {
                        alertMessage = jsonForPostExecute.getString("message");
                        alertTitle = jsonForPostExecute.getString("messagelabel");
                        creditsValue = jsonForPostExecute.getInt("credits");
                        fidelityValue = jsonForPostExecute.getInt("fidelity");
                        userStatusText = jsonForPostExecute.getString("userstatus");
                        Log.e("mytag", "pas d'erreur");

                        updateUiMethod(true);}}}
```

I tried a lot of things to avoid the crash but the app still crashes and I'm now sure that I can't figure why by myself.

Edit : Here's the whole asyncTask class :

```
     public class FetchAddCreditsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("compte", 0);
            String postContent = "platform=android&email=";
            String email = mPrefs.getString("mail", "Error");
            postContent = postContent + email + "&nb=";
            postContent = postContent + nb + "&token=";
            postContent = postContent + token + "&productID=";
            postContent = postContent + productID + "&lang=";
            String langage = mPrefs.getString("language", "error");

            postContent = postContent + langage;
            MD5Digest md5 = new MD5Digest();
            String hash = "";
            try {
                hash = md5.getMD5("hash1" + postContent + "hash2");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nb", nb));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receipt", token));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("platform", "android"));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", langage));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productid", productID));
            //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

            postContent = postContent + "&hash=" + hash;

            String url = "https://api-prod-1.l-w.mobi/addCredits";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            trustAllHosts();
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add request header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
            //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(pairs));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postContent);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            // parsing data
            jsonForPostExecute = jsonObject;

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
            // do something     
            Log.e("tag",jsonForPostExecute.toString());
            try {
                if (jsonForPostExecute.getString("error") != null) {
                        alertMessage = jsonForPostExecute.getString("message");
                        alertTitle = jsonForPostExecute.getString("messagelabel");
                        creditsValue = jsonForPostExecute.getInt("credits");
                        fidelityValue = jsonForPostExecute.getInt("fidelity");
                        userStatusText = jsonForPostExecute.getString("userstatus");
                        Log.e("mytag", "pas d'erreur");

                        updateUiMethod(true);
                } else {
                    final String errorlabel = jsonForPostExecute.getString("errorlabel");
                    final String errorMessage = jsonForPostExecute.getString("error");
                    Log.e("mytag", "il y a une erreur");


                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_Achat.this);
                    builder.setTitle(errorlabel);
                    builder.setMessage(errorMessage);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    Activity_Achat.this.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            //show AlertDialog
                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the `doInBackground()` method. Maybe you are getting the error there and not even going `onPostExecute()`. Notice also that `onPostExecute()` is executed in UI Thread

Comment: I posted the doInBackground(). So you mean I can do UI modifications directly in onPostExecute ?

Comment: Yeap. Only `doInBackground` runs on another thread. UI modifications can be made `onPostExecute`. Please try to debug `AsyncTask` and check if you can find where it is coming from.